# Chrome blocks the work of expansion

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, https

My extension send GET request on my site(http).
But Chrome recently started to block these requests, and show error :

```
The page at 'https://site' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://MYsite/zz.php?id=116174676': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
VM93 content_script.js:16(anonymous function)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Simply send the request to the HTTPS version of your website. If you don't have one you'll have to get one.

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly states, you need to load your content over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Search where in your code trying to access to http protocol, It should be https